# How to make a Scale Up Animation with Object Animator

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

When using anim, I could do something like this

```
ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1.0, 0, 1.0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
```

to scale from 0 to original size of the object.

How could I do the same with `ObjectAnimator` or `ValueAnimator`?

Comment: see `View#SCALE_X` / `View#setScaleX()` and `View#SCALE_Y` / `View#setScaleY()`

Comment: With ValueAnimator you can "animate value". For example for Scale animation, you animate scale value(In your case from 0 to 1);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use something like this for *ValueAnimator*:

```
ValueAnimator translate = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1f, 1.5f);
translate.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        float scale = Float.parseFloat(animation.getAnimatedValue().toString());
        yourView.setScaleX(scale);
        yourView.setScaleY(scale);
    }
});
translate.start();
```

---

And something like this for *ObjectAnimator*:

```
AnimatorSet animationSet = new AnimatorSet();

ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 1f, 1.5f);
ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 1f, 1.5f);

animationSet.playTogether(scaleX, scaleY);
animationSet.start();
```

---

You can also set duration/interpolator/delay and similar properties for both animations. Also do not forget to start the animation after configuring.

---

NOTE:
Did not test this code, something might not work properly.

Comment: Hi, can you also give an example for slide in animation? I mean, could I supply a percent value for slide animation using Object Animator?

Comment: "translationY" has nothing to do with scaling - use `View#SCALE_X` / `View#SCALE_Y` instead when creating `ObjectAnimator`

Comment: @ArchieQuiñones what you should do to provide a percent value for object animator is: *ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view,"scaleY", 1f, percent);* where *percent* could be something like *0.8f* (20% scale down) or *1.5f* (50% scale up)

Comment: @ArchieQuiñones and for slide animation use "translationX" for left/right slide animations, "translationY" for up/down slide animations in ObjectAnimator.

Comment: @TomasJablonskis Thank you soo much. :)

Comment: please, do not encourage using "scaleX", "translationY" etc, use `View#SCALE_X` , `View#TRANSLATION_Y` instead

Comment: @pskink I do not encourage it, I am just providing one of the ways to solve this problem even tho there are better solutions. I am thankful for your input.

Comment: animationSet.playTogether is not found

Comment: @KingofMasses that method is still working, you can check official documentation how to use it here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet . If you cannot access it you probably messed up your dependencies somewhere.